# Can Web RTC be used on the iPhone, and if so, how?

Tags: ios

Can Web RTC be used on the iPhone, and if so, how?
How can we integrate web RTC in iphone.

Comment: There are a couple of WebRTC based SDK for iOS. Check out this article:
http://bloggeek.me/webrtc-fit-ios/